# call back which called only once per ViewController creation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In swift i am looking for a callback which happen only once after a ViewController is created and shown. I come from android and the equivalent is "OnCreate" which get called once when Activity is created.

My problem is that i am loading a ViewController class and in this class i want to show an interstitial add first from the same ViewController class (full screen add) and then the other logic.

I tried using the view will appear but it get called again every time i close the add

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic in `viewDidLoad` method of `UIViewController`, which means the view  of the ViewController has been created automatically and loaded into memory, same as the `onCreate()` of `Activity` in Android.

The `viewWillAppear:` is similar to the `onResume()` callback of the `Activity`.

Comment: The problem is that if i try to present an add in the viewWillAppear i get an error that the ViewController is not in the window hierarchy

Comment: Have you set the ViewController as the `rootViewController` of the keyWindow?